# Rails application starts with wrong rails version

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to upgrade a Rails 2 application to Rails 3.

```
rails -v
```

outputs Rails 3.0.0.rc -- so, that part's good.

But...

When I do:

```
rails server
```

I just get the help

So I tried

```
script/server
```

and I get:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.2 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

I've done a global replace in the application on '2.3.2' but it STILL says it's a 2.3.2 application! Why is that???

I've followed a bunch of tutorials on this upgrade path and no luck yet. But I'm really stumped as to what keeps making it think it's a 2.3.2 application.

Comment: ah, i just had to unfreeze the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure it's found if someone else comes along -- I had to unfreeze my application. It was automatically using the rails version frozen into the app.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3 requires using [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) for package management (including Rails version), so simply replacing 2.3.2 will not work. Furthermore, the Mongrel server is now started using 'rails server' (instead of script/server).

I recommend you take a look at Ryan Bate's screencasts on upgrading from Rails 2 to Rails 3 (very well done). You can find them on [Rails Casts](http://railscasts.com/) as #225, #226 and #227.

Answer (score 0):

Your config/environment.rb file is what sets the particular version of rails that your app is running, with the following line:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.2' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

However, the process of upgrading to Rails 3 is much more involved. You will need to start by installing the [rails_upgrade plugin](http://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade) and then running a few commands to migrate some key files across. The instructions for the upgrade procedure are all here: http://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade/blob/master/install.rb